# HTTP: What header to add in order to set the charset?

Tags: java, web-services, http

I got this Java code at my RESTFul Web Service:

```
 Response response = Response.ok().
             entity(method(paramether)).
             header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
```

I want to add some header that lets me set the charset to UTF-8 through the HTTP itself (because I'm facing some problems when trying to set only at the document). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Content-Type`, e.g.:

```
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

The Content-Type header can be used to specify the type of the content you return, along with it's character set.

As an example:

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

Taken from the Wikipedia article on HTTP headers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields